# Conditional dot at the end of a section heading with \@addpunct

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to add a dot automatically to section headings. Take the following example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsgen}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectiontitleformat}[1]{%
  #1\@addpunct{.}}
\makeatother

\let\sectionx\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\sectionx{\sectiontitleformat{#1}}}

\let\paragraphx\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\paragraphx{\sectiontitleformat{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\section{A}
\end{document}
```

It results in the following error:

```
! Improper \spacefactor.
\@addpunct #1->\ifnum \spacefactor 
                                   >\@m \else #1\fi 
l.16 \section{A}
                
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

When changing the example to use `\paragraph{A}` rather than `\section{A}`, it seems to be working fine.

I also tried using `\@startsection` to define the section, but the problem still appears when setting the `afterskip` parameter to a positive value.

*EDIT*: changed the shown example to be the erroneous one.

Comment: Did you change the \paragraph to \section?

Comment: No, that fails. That ought top be your main example. You do realize that you have broken the optional argument for `\section` like this? It is probably a better idea to either use a package that provides and interface, or patch it into the internal parts

Comment: I'll edit the example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I trace it, I discover that `#1` is replaced with

```
\@hangfrom {\hskip \z@ \relax \@svsec }\interlinepenalty \@M A\@@par
```

so the `\@addpunct` command comes too late, after `\@@par` (which is the standard `\par`).

My suggestion is to use `titlesec` for this job.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsgen}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
%  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\sectiontitleformat}
%\titleformat{\subsection}
%  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}
%  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{\sectiontitleformat}
%\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
%  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectiontitleformat}[1]{#1\@addpunct{.}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Text}

\section{Text!}

\paragraph{Text}

\paragraph{Text!}

\end{document}
```

The `\titleformat` lines have been taken from the documentation of `titlesec` (page 24)

[image]